# Class not found exception for WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, relevant class in Spring Data REST

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-web

I am new to Spring Data REST, I am not supported to use methods from spring-webmvc.jar. so I am planning to use @BasePathAwareController or @RepositoryRestController but I am seeing class not found exception for WebMvcConfigurerAdapter. I know that class is available in spring-webmvc.jar but how can I over come I can paste my Spring-config.xml and web.xml

I would like to find relevant class in Spring Data REST and how to configure that in Web.xml or dispatcher-servlet.xml.

I found RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter similar to the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class but not sure how to use it.